# SQL Joins with ON statements all gathered at the end

Tags: sql-server, join

Can someone please explain the logic of this kind of join?

```
SELECT 1
FROM   TABLE1 t1
       RIGHT JOIN TABLE2 t2
               ON t1.ID = t2.ID1
       RIGHT JOIN TABLE3 t3
                  INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4
                          ON t3.ID = t4.ID3
                  INNER JOIN TABLE5 t5
                             INNER JOIN TABLE6 t6
                                     ON t5.ID = t6.ID5
                             INNER JOIN TABLE7 t7
                                        INNER JOIN TABLE8 t8
                                                   INNER JOIN TABLE9 t9
                                                              INNER JOIN TABLE0 t0
                                                                      ON t9.ID0 = t0.ID
                                                           ON t8.ID = t9.ID8
                                                ON t7.ID = t9.ID7
                                     ON t6.ID = t9.ID6
                          ON t4.ID9 = t9.ID
               ON t2.ID6 = t6.ID
```

I was hoping it might translate to something like this ...

```
select 1
FROM    TABLE1 t1
        RIGHT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID1
        INNER JOIN TABLE6 t6 ON t2.ID6 = t6.ID
        INNER JOIN TABLE9 t9 ON t6.ID = t9.ID6
        INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4 ON t4.ID9 = t9.ID 
        RIGHT JOIN TABLE3 t3 ON t3.ID = t4.ID3
        INNER JOIN TABLE5 t5 ON t5.ID = t6.ID5
        INNER JOIN TABLE7 t7 ON t7.ID = t9.ID7
        INNER JOIN TABLE8 t8 ON t8.ID = t9.ID8
        INNER JOIN TABLE0 t0 ON t9.ID0 = t0.ID
```

... but it's not the case.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's what I would have thought. But it does.

Comment: It looks like something copied out of an old copy of MS Access; I can't explain it, but I would rewrite it to the ANSI standard so someone else can read and modify it in the future.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/125422/3690

Comment: @MartinSmith can you explain a bit. Is it just some bizarre way to make a cross join?
I would like to change to a more conventional structure but I don't quite understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), page 180, the `ON` clause is part of a qualified join.  `ON` goes with `JOIN`.

You can say,

```
join R on X join S on Y
```

but do not be fooled (as I was) that you cannot say

```
join R join S on X on Y
```

because `JOIN` is recursive, as explained by the accepted answer to [What does the position of the ON clause actually mean](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125422/what-does-the-position-of-the-on-clause-actually-mean).

In `R join S`, `S` can have the form `T join U`, so what you get is

R join (join S on Y) on X

Hat tip to [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) for pointing out the correct answer.

Comment: This answer is not correct. [See explanation here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125426/3690) The syntax is fine and accepted in all the main RDBMS (though some require parentheses and some don't)   
[SQL Server](http://rextester.com/HCXS86396), [POSTGRES](http://rextester.com/XZWC24693), [ORACLE](http://rextester.com/DEOV23503)

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly valid standard SQL

```
FROM   A
       JOIN B
            JOIN C
              ON <<pred1>>
         ON <<pred2>>
```

Is equivalent to

```
FROM   A
       JOIN (SELECT ...
             FROM   B
                    JOIN C
                      ON <<pred1>>)
         ON <<pred2>>
```

So your specific case translates to something like

```
WITH t90
     AS (SELECT t9.ID  AS t9_Id,
                t0.ID  AS t0_Id,
                t9.ID6 AS t9_ID6,
                t9.ID7 AS t9_ID7,
                t9.ID8 AS t9_ID8
         FROM   TABLE9 t9
                INNER JOIN TABLE0 t0
                  ON t9.ID0 = t0.ID),
     T890
     AS (SELECT t8.ID AS t8_Id,
                t90.t9_Id,
                t90.t0_Id,
                t90.t9_ID6,
                t90.t9_ID7
         FROM   TABLE8 t8
                INNER JOIN t90
                  ON t8.ID = t90.t9_ID8),
     T7890
     AS (SELECT t7.ID AS t7_Id,
                T890.t8_Id,
                T890.t9_Id,
                T890.t0_Id,
                T890.t9_ID6
         FROM   TABLE7 t7
                INNER JOIN T890
                  ON t7.ID = t9_ID7),
     T567890
     AS (SELECT T7890.*,
                T6.ID AS T6_Id
         FROM   TABLE5 t5
                INNER JOIN TABLE6 t6
                  ON t5.ID = t6.ID5
                INNER JOIN T7890 T7890
                  ON t6.ID = T7890.t9_ID6),
     T34567890
     AS (SELECT T567890.t6_ID
         FROM   TABLE3 t3
                INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4
                  ON t3.ID = t4.ID3
                INNER JOIN T567890
                  ON t4.ID9 = T567890.t9_Id)
SELECT 1
FROM   TABLE1 t1
       RIGHT JOIN TABLE2 t2
         ON t1.ID = t2.ID1
       RIGHT JOIN T34567890
         ON t2.ID6 = T34567890.t6_ID
```

Answer (score -1):

They are not same because immediately after 
 RIGHT JOIN, LEFT join or inner join you should specify ON. (without in it will be similar to a cross join which is totally different).

So yes, the top code is totally different from the bottom code.

Also, you cannot put multiple ON  immediately after each other, if you have multiple columns to Join you should use INNER JOIN  before any ON clause.

Comment: They both may run, but the first one most probably is NOT what is the most typical use of Joins. First one without ON clause will create tons of data(similar to Cross join